# Повторное использование предлога "на"

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Допустимо ли повторное использование предлога "на" в предложении:

*Одобрить предложение Фирмы 1 об оказании спонсорской помощи Фирме 2 **на** общую сумму ...млн сумов **на** покрытие расходов, указанных в письме.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело не в том, что тут два "на". Дело в том, что оказывают помошь **в чем-то**, а не **на что-то**. Если речь идет о размере помощи, то говорят "**помощь в размере N денежных единиц**"

Как вариант, могу предложить такую формулировку:

**Одобрить предложение Фирмы А о выделении Фирме Б N денежных единиц в качестве спонсорской помощи, направленной на покрытие расходов, указанных в письме.**

Это в том случае, если спонсор оплатит расходы. А если он просто перечислит деньги Фирме Б, то

**Одобрить предложение Фирмы А о выделении Фирме Б N денежных единиц в качестве спонсорской помощи, предназначенной для покрытия расходов, указанных в письме.**

Comment: просто тут вышестоящие придрались что бы я указал на что потратят спонсорскую помощь ее получившие)))

Comment: спасибо вам, я тоже хочу научиться шпарить такие тексты

Comment: Увы, но оборот "что-то на сумму такую-то"  прочно и незыблемо занял место в деловом лексиконе. Я понимаю ваше стремление общаться высоким стилем, но вряд ли его поймут "коммерсанты".

Answer (score 1):

> Одобрить предложение Фирма1 об оказании спонсорской помощи Фирма2 на
>   общую сумму ... млн. сум. на покрытие расходов, указанных в письме.

Фраза не нарушает никаких стилистических правил, принятых в деловой переписке. Более того, я против замены первого "на сумму" на "в размере". Тут даже смысл может несколько пострадать. Такая замена хороша тогда и только тогда, если помощь выделяется непосредственно деньгами, а если как-то еще?!  Щенками борзыми? Тут уже "размер" нецместен.

Тут скорее второе "на" можно поправить.

*Одобрить предложение Фирма1 об оказании спонсорской помощи Фирма2 на общую сумму ... млн. сум. **для** покрытия расходов, указанных в письме.*

Вообще разговор о двух повторяющихся союзах - пересказ некогда популярного, но чисто субъективного мнения отдельных редакторов старой закалки. Если смысл и понимание не страдает, то зачем такое правило вводить? У вас случай пограничный. Правка совсем не обязательна, но возможна.

Comment: вот я тоже не знаю откуда это правило взялось про повторное использование одинаковых предлогов. Просто поймите меня, на работе много упертых людей старающихся доказать любыми путями свою правоту. Вот почему появляются разные правила из ряда вон выходящие. я один документ недели три переправлял то одному что то не понравится, то другому(((. наконец таки сегодня я сдал этот документ.

Comment: @АвазбекИсманов С упертыми разбирайтесь сами. Тут, на ресурсе, их тоже хватает, доказать ничего нельзя. "Правило" же просто придумали.  Реально его просто не существует, ибо нет ясно и четко написанной версии в авторитетном источнике, когда и при каких условиях его применять. Была  когда-то некая негласная договоренность на уровне "чутья". Всегда надо смотреть по контексту. Но в данной ситуации я отчасти готов согласиться, что здесь два одинаковых предлога подряд несколько сбивает с толку...

Comment: Вариант правки, который должен устроить ваших оппонентов я предложил, биться за абсолютную чистоту и правильность исходного варианта не намерен.,